# Design Pattern To save MFC Dialog Controls States

Tags: c++, design-patterns, mfc

I wrote GUI application that is written in MFC. The application have different dialog boxes. Each dialog boxes have default options, but user can come and select different options based on their need. I would like to save all the options selected by the user to a file so that when we run my application next time, i load those options was chosen by the user last time instead of default options. What is the best design pattern to do this? Right now, i have a SaveIO and LoadIO classes that interact with all the Dialog classes. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it as every time i add another dialog, i have to update the SaveIO and LoadIO classes.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd be better off distinguishing between the dialogs on one hand, and the configuration of the program on the other.

Given what you're trying to accomplish, it sounds like you want a configuration object that supports serialization, and some dialogs that can modify the current state of the configuration object.

This way, saving/restoring a configuration is just serializing/deserialzing the configuration object.

This is closely analogous to the basic document/view paradigm followed by MFC in general--the configuration object corresponds closely to a model, and the dialogs correspond to views into (parts of) that configuration object.

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be to have a 1-1 relationship between dialogs and the classes responsible for saving and loading their state. This way when you add a new dialog you only need to add 2 classes to handle saving and loading the state, and no existing code need to change.

Using conventions you should be able to figure out the name of the classes responsible for the saving and loading abased on the name of the dialogue being used.